# Error: Cannot find module check.versions with angular2-seed

Tags: angular, angular2-seed

I have a fairly fresh project start from angular2-seed.
Until yesterday, everything `npm install` was working without a problem.
Yesterday, I added another dependency into the mix (bootstrap-sass) and the post install task started to fail with the following error:

```
[01:07:09] Using gulpfile ~/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/gulpfile.js
[01:07:09] Starting 'check.versions'...
[01:07:09] 'check.versions' errored after 174 μs
[01:07:09] Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/tools/tasks/seed/check.versions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/tools/utils/seed/tasks_tools.js:107:34)
    at module.exports (/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/ShurikAg/Dev/indago/indago/journeymap/npm-debug.log
```

Right now, even if I remove the new dependency it fails.
The file of a task is in place.
I also tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling everything again, it does not help.
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Steps taken to get to this problem:

1. Install fresh seed
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`

All works

4. Do some code changes

All works

5. Add dependency manually to package.json
6. `rm -rf mode_modules`
7. `npm install`

Error as per above.

As i mentioned, since then, I tried different ways of reinstalling everything including `npm install bootstrap-sass --save`... same result.

Comment: why are you manually adding dependency `npm install (node_module_name) --save` is more than enough

Comment: Becuase the result is exactly the same. I tried both ways

Comment: in both ways it showed same error?

Comment: Right now, even if I remove the component completely I see the same error.

Comment: update your post with the steps you took to achieve this

Comment: I had to start from scratch. It was waist of time.

Answer (score 3):

try to remove gulpfile.js

I had same issue, this helped. Found solution here: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/902